# Simple docker example only appears to expose db container and not web

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I clone this [repo](https://github.com/Fingel/sane-django-docker) (it's pretty much based on docker docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/)) and run `docker-compose up`.  Docker builds the 2 containers and I see the output from db_1 (psql looks to be completely ready) but nothing at all from web_1, no output whatsoever.

I go to my host IP + 8000 and nothing is running there.  I am using docker toolbox for mac.  It's pretty much the simplest possible example of using Docker - any idea why I'm not seeing anything from my Django container?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: what's the output of `docker ps -a`? do you see a stopped web container? It could be the issue that the service inside the db container wasn't started yet and that the other webcontainer already wanted to start but couldn't connect with the db.

Comment: Looks like both containers are up

Answer (score 0):

it might be possible that STDOUT of the web_1 Container is mapped only to display WARN and ERROR level. You say youre using Docker Toolbox for Mac? Have you tried to reach the Website over the IP of the DockerToolBox VM or the HostIP? Im not quite aware with DockerToolbox since there is an native MacClient (https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/). Maybe try to reach the DockerToolboxIp not HostIP. I would also recommend to use Docker for Mac native, since i had problems with the ToolBox but none with the "Native" Client.
Hope i could Help

Comment: Yep, I'm trying to access at DockerToolBox VM IP.  I did a test with tomcat container and i could access that fine.  Unfortunately, I have a mid 2010 mac and the processor is not supported for Docker for mac native.

Comment: Well sounds like a weird NAT Issue with the ToolBox VM. Open Virtualbox Manager and change dockertoolbox VM´s networking mode to bridge. So it assigns an IP from your DHCP. I ran into this issue with Toolbox aswell. Sometimes the NATing seems to be weird. Try to rerun docker-compose up and than visit the new IP of DockerToolbox, which should be one of your Local network. So no NATing Issues should appear.

Comment: Docker toolbox uses VirtualBox underneath, you could use that to give you a terminal into the VM hosting your containers. I'd bet the site is accessible from inside the VM on 8000.

Comment: The new docker for Mac does not depend on VirtualBox anymore. "A faster and more reliable native development environment by using hypervisor support built into each platform. (No more VirtualBox!)" https://blog.docker.com/2016/06/docker-mac-windows-public-beta/

Answer (score 0):

After taking a better look to the documentation I was able to start your containers.
After the `git clone`:

```
cd sane-django-docker
docker-compose up -d
```

This is the output

```
Starting sanedjangodocker_db_1
Starting sanedjangodocker_web_1
[root@localhost sane-django-docker]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
cde9e93c1a70        sanedjangodocker_web   "python3 manage.py ru"   19 seconds ago      Up 1 seconds        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   sanedjangodocker_web_1
73ad8cafe798        postgres:9.4           "/docker-entrypoint.s"   20 seconds ago      Up 1 seconds        5432/tcp                 sanedjangodocker_db_1
```

When I just performd docker-compose up (running in the forground I saw this issue).

```
LOG:  shutting down
LOG:  database system is shut down
```

After taking a better look in [the documentation](http://www.pedaldrivenprogramming.com/2015/10/sane-django-development-with-docker/) I saw the problem

> Django will complain about the postgres database not existing so we'll
>   create one:

```
docker exec sanedjangodocker_db_1 createdb -Upostgres webapp
```

Now the postgres is fine but I had to restart the webapp to find the db.

```
docker restart sanedjangodocker_web_1
```

Now I'm able to acces it on IP:8000

```
It worked!
Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.
```

I don't know how the django app really works but the setup is pretty strange.